# calculation of limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

The limit
$$\displaystyle\lim _{x\to 0}\frac {1}{x}\int_x^{2x}e^{-t^2}dt$$

1. Does not exist.
2. Is infinite.
3. Exists and equals to $1$.
4. Exists and equals to $ 0$.

I don't know how to solve it, please give some hints.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried looking at the mean value theorem for integrals?

Comment: Posting this because it is entirely elementary: using the change of variable $t=xu$ with $dt=xdu$ and the fact that, for every $u$ in $(1,2)$, $e^{-x^2u^2}\to1$ when $x\to0$, one gets $$\frac {1}{x}\int_x^{2x}e^{-t^2}dt=\int_1^{2}e^{-x^2u^2}du\to\int_1^{2}du=1.$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $f (x)=\int_0^xe^{-t^2}\,dt $. Then, using the Mean Value Theorem, 
$$
\frac1x\,\int_x^{2x}e^{-t^2}\,dt=\frac {f (2x)-f (x)}x=f'(c)=e^{-c^2} $$ for some $c $ between $x $ and $2x $. As $x\to0$, we also have $c\to0$, so by continuity of the exponential the limit is $e^0=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $1-t^2 \leq e^{-t^2} \leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be infinite ways of doing this problem, but the way I tackled it was using L'Hopital's rule:

> L'Hopital's rule states that for functions $f$ and $g$, if 
>   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow c} f(x) =\lim_{x\rightarrow c} g(x) = 0 $$
>   then so long as it exists:
>   $$\lim_{x\rightarrow c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow c} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

In this particular example, we want to find:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\int_x^{2x} e^{-t^2}dt}{x}$$

where both the top and bottom are functions of $x$ that approach zero as $x$ approaches zero. So on application of L'Hopital's rule we have:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\int_x^{2x} e^{-t^2}dt}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^{2x} e^{-t^2}dt}{\frac{d}{dx}x}$$

Now we can figure out what the top part is through an application of the fundamental theorem of calculus (ish). Contemplate the existence of a function $F(x)$ such that $F'(x) = e^{-t^2}$. Then for the top part we have:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^{2x} e^{-t^2}dt = \frac{d}{dx} [F(x)]_x^{2x} = \frac{d}{dx}(F(2x)-F(x)) = 2F'(2x) - F(x)$$
$$ = 2e^{-4x^2}-e^{-x^2}$$

So putting this all together we have:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\int_x^{2x} e^{-t^2}dt}{x}  = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{2e^{-4x^2}-e^{-x^2}}{1} = 1$$